# Why is the collection view not reloading?

Tags: ios, swift

I am populating an array from data in parse. The array is being populated, but when I add it to the collection view and refresh the view, nothing shows up. How do I fix this? Is there a certain place where I have to refresh the collection view? The array is populated: [image]

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);

    getFriendName()
    getFriendPic()


}

 func getFriendPic(){

    let imagequery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    imagequery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {( objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       // for object in objects!{
            var user = PFUser.currentUser()
            let relation = user!.relationForKey("Friendship")
            relation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                for object in objects!{
                let userPic = object["ProPic"] as! PFFile
                userPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if(error == nil){
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        self.arrayOfFriends.append(image!)
                        print(self.arrayOfFriends)

                    }
                   self.collectionView.reloadData()  
            })

            }

        }
    }
}

func getFriendName(){
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var user = PFUser.currentUser()
            let relations = user!.relationForKey("Friendship")
            relations.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]
                for i in 0...(objectIDs.count){
                self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
                print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)

            }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }



    })

}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: friendcellView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! friendcellView




    cell.friendname.text = arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item]
    cell.friendpic.image =  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item]
    cell.friendpic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.friendpic.frame.size.width/2;
    cell.friendpic.clipsToBounds = true


    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfFriendsNames.count
}
```

Comment: Please post more code where you return the num of cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `arrayOfFriendsNames`. So try to `reload` like this

```
func getFriendName(){
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            var user = PFUser.currentUser()
            let relations = user!.relationForKey("Friendship")
            relations.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]
                for i in 0...(objectIDs.count){
                    self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
                    print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)

                }

            /// here
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }

           }

    })

}
```

Comment: I went ahead and put the getfriendpic and name in the view will appear (look at updated code), but sometimes it loads, sometimes the collection view is blank, and sometimes it crashes.

Comment: I'm getting it know, but the images are in different order. I think it is because it is being saved in the wrong order. Is there anyway to get it to save in order? and it still appears sometimes.

Comment: @xxtmanxx You should check your DB. But the first one, you should mix `getFriendName()` and `getFriendPic()` to 1 function. Maybe you can post another question for it.

Comment: If I were to group those under one function, how would that function? Can you have multiple functions under one function?

Comment: @xxtmanxx I think you should post another topic. Someone is good with DB will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be reloading your collection view after your closure is finished executing when you've retrieved the data from Parse, not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
        let relations = user!.relationForKey("Friendship")
        relations.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]
            for i in 0...(objectIDs.count){
            self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
            print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)

        }
    }
})
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```